# Java, JDA. How create channel?

Tags: java, database, lib

I can't create a channel. I created a button for the message, I need it to create a channel when it is pressed, with access to it for the player who pressed the button, and for the moderators

```
Guild guild = event.getJDA().getGuildById("957265304180887642");
            if (guild != null) {
                Category category = guild.getCategoryById("1131306931991101522");
                if (category != null) {
                    guild.createTextChannel("Поддержка игрока " + event.getUser().getName())
                            .setParent(category)
                            .addPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById("957267206914330665"), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL), null)
                            .addPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById("957266939577765928"), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL), null)
                            .addPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById("957266149735792731"), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL), null)
                            .addPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById("957265799654043678"), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL), null)
                            .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL))
                            .queue();
                }
            }
```

When you click on the button, it says "interaction error". help me please